# Gradle project sync failed in Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

As I open Android Studio it displays an error saying Gradle project sync failed, basic functionality will not work properly.
Also underneath it display an error:

> This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running.

What do I do as I have completely uninstalled and re-installed Android Studio several times but the issue is not resolved?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Solved same problem a moment ago, go to `File->Project Structure->SDK Location` and in **JDK Location** section unmark **use embedded JDK**, instead select location where JDK is installed(`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111`), this error is generated by changement of JDK source file by Android Studio, hope it helps.

Comment: This worked, I'm able to run app in emulator, does this mean Android sdk is configured properly ? Can you help me locating Android sdk. The Android sdk path shown in File>project structure is not visible in c directory !